# How does an integral change the distribution of a random variable?

Tags: probability, integration, reference-request, random-variables, random-functions

Suppose I have a random variable $x$, and I want to perform the integral of a function of $x$ such that:
$$y=f(x)=\int_{c_l}^{c_u} f(x,c) dc$$
where $f(x,c)$ is a nonlinear function of $x$ and $c$. Definitely $y$ is going to be random variable dependent on $x$. **If $y$ does not have a closed form expression is there a way to find the distribution of $y$**, given distribution of $x$.

I have studied a little about transformation of random variables, but there integrals are not considered.

**Though the question has been answered. I will be grateful if one can provide me some literature regarding same. This will help me in knowing things better.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say $Y = \int_0^1 f(X, t) dt$ (since $c_u, c_l$ are fixed, we may as well assume they are $0$ and $1$ for simplicity). I will denote $I(x) := \int_0^1 f(x, t) dt.$ To compute the desired density, we will make a rather strong assumption, but as I showed in [this other MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007356/radon-nikodym-derivative-fracd-mathbbp-xd-mathbbq-x-from-fracd/4009602#4009602) we cannot say a lot more in the general setting. Thus we will make the assumption that $I$ is invertible and differentiable with respect to $x$ (implicitly here we make assumptions on $f(\cdot, \cdot),$ which may for example be consulted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)). Note that the density of a random variable $X$ is nothing more than the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) of the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) $X_* \mathbb{P}$ of $X$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda,$ where we have denoted by $\mathbb{P}$ the measure on the domain of the random variable. The following discussion will rely on the notions mentioned above, so I do urge you to familiarise yourself with them.

We have that $Y = I(X)$ and we want to compute the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d I_* X_* \mathbb{P}}{d \lambda}.$ Since we assumed the necessary conditions to make $I$ differentiable, we have that $I'(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, t) dt$. Let us also denote the density of $X$ by $g.$ It follows by basic results concerning Radon-Nikodym derivatives and the ones linked above that:
$$d I_* X_* \mathbb{P}  = \frac{d I_* X_* \mathbb{P}}{d I_* \lambda} \frac{d I_* \lambda}{d \lambda} d \lambda = \frac{d X_* \mathbb{P}}{d \lambda} \circ I^{-1} (I^{-1})' d \lambda,$$
so the density of $Y$ is given by $$ \rho(x) = g(I^{-1}(x)) \frac{1}{\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (I^{-1}(x), t) dt}.$$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Are there any book (reference) where I can read more about this, random variable transformation using Radon-Nikodym Theorem? I mean the books that I know talk about general random variable transformations and not one with Radon-Nikodym derivatives.